# protecting route to classic asp files in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp-classic

I have to run a classic asp project in the root folder of a mvc folder.

How can i set up the web config to protect the routes through classic asp files?

I tried the following but now i'm not having access to anything....

```
<location path="Account">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="/">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The Controller will get a [Authorize(Users = "*")] to protect them from anonymous users.

Regards
float

Comment: What do you mean by protecting access to classic asp files? Should those files be visible/executed only authenticated users of the ASP.NET MVC site?

Comment: Yes, all files (*.asp, *.pdfs etc) of the classic asp site should be accessible only to authenticated users of the MVC Page.

Comment: @float, by *accessible* do you mean they should be downloadable as plain text files or executable?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, asp files should get executed by iis (so the authenticated user can see the website), pdfs and docs etc should be downloadable (if a authenticated user decides to click a download link)

Comment: @float, what authentication are you using: basic, forms, NTLM, Digest, ...?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I'm using forms authentication with a custom membership provider.

Comment: @float, so authenticated users are not tracked by IIS but by the ASP.NET MVC application. That's problematic for what you are trying to achieve. Because the classic ASP pages are considered as separate applications. You might need to modify them in order to read and decrypt the authentication cookie emitted by the ASP.NET MVC application and test if the user is authenticated or not before executing. As far as the static files are concerned you might need to move them to a secure, non-accessible folder and serve them through a dynamic handler which will check authentication.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, at the moment, I'm telling the classic asp page if the user is authenticated through the server variable "auth_user" at the first start of a classic asp file and set session variables with the roles the user have. The static files are the bigger problem, because this the site has a huge amount of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my Problem. I had to add following lines to the web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
<!-- allow specific mvc files/folders -->
<location path="Content">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Home">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<!-- allow specific asp files/folders -->
<location path="logout.asp">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```